# Advantage of STL resize()

Tags: c++, stl

The `resize()` function makes vector contain the required number of elements. If we require less elements than vector already contain, the last ones will be deleted. If we ask vector to grow, it will enlarge its size and fill the newly created elements with zeroes.

```
 vector<int> v(20); 
 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
     v[i] = i+1; 
    } 
  v.resize(25); 

 for(int i = 20; i < 25; i++) { 
     v[i] = i*2; 
   }
```

But if we use `push_back()` after `resize()`, **it will add elements AFTER the newly allocated size, but not INTO it.** In the example above the size of the resulting vector is 25, while if we use push_back() in a second loop, it would be 30.

```
 vector<int> v(20); 
 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
     v[i] = i+1; 
  } 
 v.resize(25); 
  for(int i = 20; i < 25; i++) { 
  v.push_back(i*2);   // Writes to elements with indices [25..30), not [20..25) ! <
 }
```

Then where is the advantage of `resize()` function ? Doesn't it creates a confusion for indexing and accessing elements from the vector ?

Comment: "If we ask vector to grow, it will enlarge its size and fill the newly created elements with zeroes." That's your answer right there. Why would it over-write it's newly created default-constructed elements? `resize` adds elements, `reserve` saves the space for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds as though you should be using [`vector::reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/).

[`vector::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) is used to **initialize the newly created space** with a given value (or just the default.) The second parameter to the function is the initialization value to use.

Answer (score 4):

Remember the alternative - [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/). `resize` is used when you want to act on the vector using the `[]` operator -- hence you need a "empty" table of elements. `resize` is not intended to be used with `push_back`. Use `reserve` if you want to prepare the array for `push_back`.

Resize is mainly usefull if the array has  meaningful "empty" constructor, when you can create an array of empty elements, and only change the ones that are meaningful.

Comment: @GMan, duh, I (as usually) confused it with `at()` -_-. No reason to downvote though.

Comment: Never, @GMan? I think it's unspecified. It could throw if the implementer chose to make it throw. The standard doesn't say one way or the other. To guarantee an exception, use `at` instead.

Comment: @GMan, sorry for the accusation then. Wonder why it did get downvoted then... Ironically, sorry even more :)

Comment: @Rob: You're semi-right. It's undefined behavior to access an out-of-bounds element with `[]`; so I'm wrong saying it can't ever throw. But it's not unspecified per se, just anything could happen. @Kornel: No problems.

Comment: @Rob and @GMan, this poses an interesting question though -- is there an implementation that throws on out-of-bounds `[]` query? A debug mode with such a feature would be extremely useful.

Comment: @Kornel: Well, MSVC++ asserts in debug mode (and in release if you don't specify otherwise.) I don't know about other compilers; I assume they'd do the same. But I doubt any throw. Doing so requires a check, and the point of `[]` over `at` is to skip the check. And if it's gonna be debug only, might as well make it assert instead.

Comment: @GMan, fair enough. Just checked it (hate browsing through MSVC STL implementation).

Answer (score 3):

The `resize()` method changes the vector's [`size`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/vector/size), which is not the same as the vector's [`capacity`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/vector/capacity).

It is very important to understand the distinction between these two values:

- The `size` is the number of actual elements that the vector contains.
- The `capacity` is the maximum number of elements that the vector could contain without reallocating a larger chunk of memory.

A vector's `capacity` is always larger or equal to its `size`. A vector's `capacity` never shrinks, even when you reduce its `size`, with one exception: when you use `swap()` to exchange the contents with another vector. And as others have mentioned, you can increase a vector's `capacity` by calling `reserve()`.

I think that using the correct terminology for `size` and `capacity` makes it easier to understand the C++ `vector` class and to speak clearly about its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

resize() function changes the actual content of the vector by inserting or erasing elements from the vector. It does not only change its storage capacity. To direct a change only in storage capacity, use vector::reserve instead. Have a look at the vector visualization in the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B)), notice where v.back is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the confusion. The advantage of `resize` is that it resizes your vector. Having to do a loop of `push_back`s is both tedious and may require more than one "actual" resize.

If you want to "resize" your vector without changing its accessible indexes then use `std::vector<T>::reserve`. That will change the size of the internal allocated array without actually "adding" anything.